# can someone tell what's wrong with this code,it gets terminates instantly on execution

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

the given code is trying to initialise matrix using using pointer for dynamic memory allocation

```
int main()
{

    int **a;
    *a=new int[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        a[i]=new int[3];
        a[i]=0;
    }
    cout<<"Enter 3x3 Matrix : "; 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cin>>a[i][j];   
        }
    }
    //display matrix
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" "; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    delete a[i];
    delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

just getting terminate instantly on execution without taking any input...

Comment: This is an example of where a [mre] can be a useful debugging tool. Start by determining where the crash occurs. A debugger could tell you this with little effort, but trial-and-error works too. Remove about the second half of your `main` function and try compiling and running again. Repeat that until the crash disappears. When the crash disappears, add back one line at a time until the crash returns. You now know which line to focus on.

Comment: `a` is uninitialised.  Assigning to `*a`  (i.e.  `*a = new int[3]`) therefore has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The line `*a=new int[3];` might cause the program to crash.

As `a` is not initialized, attempting to write to `*a` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)(UB).

One way of solving this is by writing `a = new int[3]`, but this will not compile because `a` is `int **`(a pointer to pointer to `int`), and not `int *`.
One way of appeasing the compiler is by making `a = new int*[3]`, this will allocate a pointer to an array of 3 pointers to integer.

After that, there is another thing that makes the code fail:

On the line `a[i]=new int[3];` you assign a value of a newly allocated array of integers to `a[i]`, that is fine, but then you write `a[i]=0;`, this changes the pointers to a `NULL` value, so the code fail when you try to write to `a[i][j]`.

(I believe) You might want to initialize the allocated array to 0. On that case, you should do another `for` that sets each `a[i][j]` to 0.

There's also an subtle issue when you free the array. I believe you expect `a[i]` to be a pointer to an array, so you should use `delete[] a[i]` instead of `delete a[i]`. Using the wrong `delete`(`[]` or not)  also is UB.